# ColorBox is sized too small the first time content is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

According to this [FAQ](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq#faq-img), my problem occurs in cases where the image is not finished loaded before ColorBox measures the size of the box. The second time it will load from cache, hence ColorBox will know the image size.

The resolution suggested in the FAQ is to set the image size in advance.

My problem is that my images varies in width and length, and I don't have anyway of knowing the size of the image in advance. Is there any known solution for such a case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should consider sharing more about your project; that will probably elicit more help from the community.  In general, front-end scripts have very limited access to digital media until it is actually loaded into the DOM. ColorBox waits for the asset to be loaded into the DOM to acquire its dimensions.  But as the FAQ suggests, there are work arounds.  If your images are of random dimensions, unknowable in advance, you'll find that ANY lightbox plugin will leave you unsatisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `jQuery.colorbox.resize()` after it renders.
It'll make `colorbox` recalculate it's height and width.

Comment: Didn't do the work. I also tried it myself, and also tried to delay it 2 seconds after the `.onload` and `.oncomplete`. The window is not resizing

Comment: @eranh Can you jsfidle it ? www.jsfiddle.com.br